# How to make sequence diagram?

Tags: curriculum-design, methods

I want to make the sequence diagram of my project..
what should i do to make it easily? Anybody know any Site then give me the link.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question, like some others lately, is off topic here. The site is for teachers looking for better ways to teach.

Comment: paper+pencil+eraser is usually a good start, before using any software to produce the final version. First decide what you want it to look like.

Comment: A sequence diagram is one of the few UML diagrams that is truly useful. Umbrello is a UML drawing tool, give it a try.